# Redirecting input from a file to a Python script fails but works with pipe

Tags: bash, scripting, python, io-redirection

I have this python script: [`postpycess.py`](https://gist.github.com/SignificantCell2/bdfe68f8e689ad78b7f91c72c92c6ea0) to draw data from a mesh file [`airfoil.p3d`](https://gist.github.com/SignificantCell2/8228a31a6757b269bc20e92a7d2490c3). This script was designed to work with input not using arguments, so I created an input file `commands.txt` and redirect it to the script.

**commands.txt**: (note that the first input which is the name of the airfoil should be provided without extension `.p3d`)

```
airfoil
1
1
q
q
```

In Windows I could run this as follows:

```
python postpycess.py < commands.txt
```

But Unfortunately, When I run that command on Ubuntu 20.04, the script fails:

```
The current working dir: /tmp/allworks/python/mwe

This is Postpycess, the CFD postprocessor
Version: 1.1
.p3dr project name: Error: can't read the file airfoil
```

However, the following works just file:

```
printf 'airfoil\n1\n1\nq\nq\n' | python postpycess.py
```

I've tried hard to narrow down the cause in the python script and create a minimal example that could reproduce the same issue without success.

Could you please, explain why redirecting the input from the file fails in Linux?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `commands.txt` has probably its lines terminated by `\r\n` (windows-style) instead of just `\n` (unix-style).

Just convert it to unix with `sed -i 's/\r//' commands.txt` or run your script as `sed 's/\r//' commands.txt | python postpycess.py`.

Comment: Oh, brilliant, that's solves the issue.

Comment: Also `dos2unix` removes carriage returns